# Hive cannot query the tables save by calling saveAsTable in Spark

Tags: hadoop, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to use Hive to query the tables I saved using saveAsTable() provided by Spark DataFrame. Everything works well when I query using hiveContext.sql(). However, when I switch to hive and describe the table, it becomes col, array, something like this and is no longer queryable.

Any ideas how to work it through? Is there a reliable way to make Hive understands the metadata defined in spark instead of explicitly defining the schema?

Sometimes I make use of spark to infer schema from the raw data or read schema from certain file formats like parquet so don't want to create these table that could be inferred automatically.

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Comment: Do you have any code sample?

Comment: Even i am facing the same issue. Does anyone has any solution for this?